# Django get ID of Max after GROUP BY

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

I have two models:

```
Forum: pk (ID)
Thread: pk (ID), last_activity (datetime), forum (foreign key)
```

I want to retrieve all the latest threads, group them by `forum` and in addition to that get at least the ID of each latest thread.

Here's what I tried:

```
Thread.objects.values(
    'forum'
).annotate(
    latest=Max('last_activity')
).order_by()
```

Here's what it produces:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'forum': 1, 'latest': datetime.datetime(...)}, 
    {'forum': 2, 'latest': datetime.datetime(...)}, 
    {'forum': 3, 'latest': datetime.datetime(...)}, 
    {'forum': 4, 'latest': datetime.datetime(...)}, 
    {'forum': 5, 'latest': datetime.datetime(...)}, 
    {'forum': 6, 'latest': datetime.datetime(...)}
]>
```

And what it should produce additionally for each entry in the queryset is the ID of the thread that has the greatest value of `latest`. Here's a sample entry:

```
{'forum': 6, 'latest': datetime.datetime(...), thread_id: 60}
```

Here's the raw query it produces:

```
SELECT "forumapp_thread"."forum_id",
       MAX("forumapp_thread"."last_activity") AS "latest"
FROM "forumapp_thread"
GROUP BY "forumapp_thread"."forum_id"
ORDER BY "forumapp_thread"."forum_id" ASC
```

Here's the query I want:

```
SELECT "forumapp_thread"."forum_id",
       "forumapp_thread"."id",
       MAX("forumapp_thread"."last_activity") AS "latest"
FROM "forumapp_thread"
GROUP BY "forumapp_thread"."forum_id"
ORDER BY "forumapp_thread"."forum_id" ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve what you want using subquery (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions).

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
latest = Thread.objects.filter(forum=OutRef('pk')).order_by(-'last_activity')
Forum.objects.annotate(latest=Subquery(latest.values('last_activity')[:1]), thread_id=Subquery(latest.values('pk')[:1]))
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work.

Comment: This should work. It's even the same situation, but for some reason: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1`. Is it because of SQLite maybe?

Comment: Try splitting the annotation in two field: 
    Forum.objects.annotate(latest=Subquery(latest.values('last_activity')[:1]), thread_id=Subquery(latest.values('pk')[:1])

Answer (score -1):

we can `F` objects for this case.

```
from django.db.models import F, Max

Thread.objects.values('forum').annotate(
    latest=Max('last_activity'), thread_id=F('id')
).order_by()
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions

Comment: I tried to do that too but all it does is it creates another group. I end up with not 6 entries (for each forum) but with N entries, where N is the number of threads in my DB.